# Running docker using linux kernel 4.3.0 got iptables nat error

Tags: docker, iptables

I upgrade my debian kernel into 4.3.0

> root@qa-control-nce-yuztest1:/usr/src/kernels/linux-4.3# uname -a
>   Linux qa-control-nce-yuztest1 4.3.0 #1 SMP Thu Dec 10 00:47:22 CST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bug found docker daemon ha

```
root@qa-control-nce-yuztest1:/usr/src/kernels/linux-4.3# docker -d
Warning: '-d' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
WARN[0000] please use 'docker daemon' instead.          
WARN[0000] Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors. For more information, see https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-storage-driver-option 
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
WARN[0000] Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section. 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "devicemapper" 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: Failed to create NAT chain: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

Seems iptables nat table does not exist, but i don't know how to deal with that.

Need your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need a kernel with iptables nat configured. I suspect because you upgraded the kernel yourself, that means you are not using one provided by a distro? In which case maybe you configured it from scratch and did not enable iptables nat.

When running the config ('make menuconfig'), search for '_nat', and find the iptables nat configuration through that, and enable it.